# Disk space used by ImageMagick/Ghostscript

Tags: windows-7, pdf, disk-space, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have a 200 MB PDF file `input.pdf` consisting of scanned images, whose resolution I want to reduce.

Under Windows 7 the following command

```
convert -density 200x200 -quality 60 -compress jpeg input.pdf output.pdf
```

is taking up *huge* amounts of disk space. I only have 25 GB free at the moment, after that was used up, Ghostscript (ImageMagick first calls Ghostscript) stopped with the error message:

```
Last OS error: No space left on device
```

How can I avoid it taking up so much disk space?

Comment: A very first short term solution would be chopping up the document into smaller chunks and process them, and finally reassemble the document. Another approach would be using Acrobat (Pro) with its wide range of file optimizing tools.

Comment: Did you try `pdftoppm -r 200` from `xpdf` You can [download it for windows too](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). Else you can always extract the original images `convert -density 200 input.pdf[0] image0.jpg` (note that you can change the page number starting from `0`)  and assemble them together again after that. In a script of course.